# Anyone using "Google Cloud Storage Fuse" in production?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, fuse, gcsfuse

How has the it's performance and stability been for you?

I'm looking to maybe implement this on a cluster to avoid a network or clustered file system and it should fit well with auto scaling the cluster of servers. But what are the con's involved in doing this? Such as price?

Comment: I believe the proper place to ask this would be http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform since this is not programming related whatsoever.